# Can I inherit iptable rules on/under windows?

Tags: networking, windows, firewall, virtual-machine

Don't really want to purchase a VPS just to test some iptables stuff for my gameserver. Was curious if it's possible to load up debian on vmware player and install nginx, nodejs, mysql, etc (which is the easy part), but then... when I do my iptables on the debian virtual machine can those rules be inherited and work on my main windows installation? Or would I need to dual boot?

Edit: Reason I ask is because I want to fiddle around with iptables before going live. I prefer iptables much better over windows firewall :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's mostly about Windows. It would be on-topic on [su].

Comment: If you just want to play inside the VM, you can, of course. It won't affect your Windows machine. But then a VPS wouldn't either.

Comment: Yeah, no problem thanks i'll try super user. Honestly, I think I should just buy a cheap 1-2$ VPS to play around with iptables... I just got back from making this question like 20 minutes ago.. I messed up some drives and master boot records trying to dual boot cause I'm an idiot :P

Comment: Why would the rules have to apply to your Windows host OS? A VPS is also just a VM. You can test the exact same things in the exact same way.

Answer (score 1):

That would be possible if you set up your Debian vm as a router and don't have any direct network connection from the Windows host to the outside. Although I think the arrangement would be even more fiddly than the Windows firewall.

Comment: Hmm. Probably be easier to dual boot or just setup the debian server on a extra laptop or something eh? :P Thanks for your insight. ~ I just gotta have iptables :D

Comment: Or put windows in the virtual machine inside Linux.

Comment: I don't thing that Linux can firewall a Microsoft's Windows machine, if they are dual booting.